# NGINX restrict IP addresses based on $arg

Tags: nginx

With nginx how do I restrict to certain IP addresses based on regexp of $args

eg

for https://somewhere.invalid/login the URI location

```
location /login {
    allow 1.2.3.4;
    deny all;
}
```

makes sense

but how do I allow /login to all but restrict by IP where $args = "person=super"

eq
https://somewhere.invalid/login?person=super

nginx does not allow "allow" statements in "if" blocks.

```
location /login {
    allow all;
    if ( $args ~ /person=super/ ) {
        allow 1.2.3.4;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Does it make any difference if the location block / is a proxy_pass ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documentation [says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) `allow` and `deny` directives cannot be used in the **if** context. Allowed contexts are **http**, **server**, **location** and **limit_except**. However you can achieve the same behavior with two [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) blocks checking [`$arg_person`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) and [`$remote_addr`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_addr) variable values:

```
map $arg_person $deny {
    super    $checkip;
    # default value will be an empty string
}
map $remote_addr $checkip {
    1.2.3.4  '';
    # you can add other allowed IPs here
    default  1;
}

server {
    ...
    location /login {
        if ($deny) { return 403; }
        ...
    }
}
```