# Restrict access to specific endpoint unless certain header value given

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

As I explained in title I want to restrict access unless the header is satisfied. In the [given link](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/161), it is explained how to restrict a specific path access, however I couldn't find anything about how to add conditions to this restriction from my researches. Any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `deny`/`allow` directives you can check any HTTP header value via [`$http_<name>`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) variable and use `return 403` to forbid access. For example, lets call our header `X-Secret-Token`:

```
location /some/path {
    if ($http_x_secret_token != 'my-super-secret-password') {
        return 403; # HTTP 403 Forbidden, the same code as generated by 'deny' directive
    }
    ...
}
```

If you need some complex checks, you can use several chained [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) blocks (see the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448798/7121513)).

Comment: I have tried this but didnt work. When I check the logs I saw response 200. I am working on configmap file. Do you have any idea about what I might miss?

Comment: Any chances some other location is overtaken request processing from this one?

Answer (score 0):

From the research I've made it seems like the token approach presented here before seems to be the only suitable solution, a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970620/nginx-reject-request-if-header-is-not-present-or-wrong).